# Steps to create a custom version of a luarocks

Tags: lua, openresty, luarocks

There is a luarocks library that I need to customize.

Say I install it using:

```
sudo luarocks install lua-abc
```

If I want my own internal custom version of this library, how could I add this to my openresty server?

Does luarocks simply download the code from github and then save it to a particular folder?  (if yes, which folder?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if the package contains any external dependencies in form of C libraries then it downloads the files & compile them and copy into *default* path.
Usually the default paths are:

- external C libraries `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.*`
- libraries `/usr/local/share/lua/5.*`

rocks are downloaded into `/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/`

Comment: So this means that openresty will look in the /lsr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks path files that you require like:  ```local http = require "resty.http"```  ?

Comment: `/lsr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks` is used to store rock files & installation purposes only

Comment: @Blankman By the way, just for clarification do you want to create a new custom lua rock or customize current installed version for your needs?

Comment: There is a lua rocks that I want to customize.  I then want to get my customized version on my server.  I copied the lua rocks, customized it, but when I push to my server I noticed i don't have the dependancies like resty.http

Comment: @Blankman Did you try to add dependency into your rockspec file then?

Answer (score 1):

LuaRocks is really shifty when it comes to using your own executable names AND your compiler CC. Some dependencies like cmake are required to operate as LuaRocks doe download C and C++ sources to compile into shared libraries, for example LuaSocket will generate a file `core.so`, which require will execute the `luaopen_libluasocket(lua_State* L);` function whomst resides in the .so file.

In order for me to use LuaRocks with LuaConsole (my replacement CLI app for lua.c and soon to be luac.c), I had to modify the actual files post-install. Here is the link: https://github.com/tilkinsc/LuaConsole/wiki/LuaRocks-Support-Linux-GCC

Basically the gist is: LuaRocks defaults to the use-case for the developers rather than average gi-joe. So go ahead and run your `./configure` which I am not sure if it supports `--prefix=XXX` But then you need to edit the `site_config_x_x.lua` file to add in `site_config.LUA_INTERPRETER=[[luaw]] -- name of lua interpreter` along with switching the actual call to the interpreter inside of luarocks shell script. That specific part is better explained here: https://github.com/tilkinsc/LuaConsole/wiki/LuaRocks-Support-Windows-MinGW Where I literally did this `"luaw" "C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\luarocks.lua" "-n" %*` instead of whatever they did... and %* is aka all arguments aka passing all arguments.

Then after that is all said and done, you are tasked with setting LUA_CPATH and LUA_PATH to search for your files. It changes based on the installation, but a command to find that out is `luarocks path --bin` which dumps it out. You can add it to the LUA_INIT env var if you want, but I am on windows and dynamically set my own path variable by using this: https://gist.github.com/tilkinsc/f6718ca61d76085b064c3dca02f96017 Alternatively, you can set package.path and package.cpath yourself... but I do not recommend.

LuaRocks is great once you get it to work :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd /usr/local/src/
```

> Download the required release from [Browse Here](https://luarocks.github.io/luarocks/releases/)

```
tar -xvf luarocks-3.2.1.tar.gz
cd luarocks-3.2.1

./configure
make build
sudo make install
```